# How would you calculate average time to make a breath?

Tags: mean

Suppose I wanted to know a one minute average of the time it takes to make a breath. So basically I would record the number of times I made a breath during one minute (one inhale and one exhale) and divide by 60 seconds to get the 1 minute average time to make a single breath? Would this be a distribution with a standard deviation?

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use 60 divided by the number of breaths, not the other way around.  Consider if you take 20 breaths; then the average length of each breath is 60/20 = 3 seconds.

Doing this once will give you a single observation; so it won't have a distribution and standard deviation as such.  However, if you do it multiple times you will get a slightly different answer each time (particularly if don't round eg you can record if you take 20.3 breaths, not just whole breaths -as ideally you should).  That set of observations will have a distribution and everything that goes along with it, including shape and standard deviation.

Rounding will definitely be a problem if precision is important.  It would be mitigated by using a longer test period than a minute.

Comment: At a particular time $t$, if you want to know the one minute average of the time it takes to make a breath, you would have to consider the data points in the past?

Comment: Well, given that the results are pretty variable, you want more than one observation in an average, and you can't average with data points you haven't seen yet, so necessarily some of your average would be into the past.